# I am looking for help about how to implement linkedin search job/people/content from ios application

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, swift5

I am looking for help about how to implement linkedin search job/people/content from ios application. 
I am getting 403 for all api except login and profile details. Infact Can I even get those details ? Does linkedin provide ?

I am using v2 as described by linkedin. I  have requested got marketing permission. Does it helps ? I tried one project from github of 
//  Created by Li Jiantang on 19/11/2015.
//  Copyright © 2015 Carma. All rights reserved.

as written in Viewcontroller

Comment: what does linkedIn documentation say about that?

Comment: I shall have to be partner. So, is the only way ? Is it like only profile are available for public rest api , for accessing, have to be partnered ?